# Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not a function evaluating 'departureloc.map' occurs when mapping for setState in react native

Tags: javascript, google-maps, react-native, google-directions-api

I am successful on getting through the JSON response from Google Directions as i am trying to get to the transit information from the json response which is initially looks like this when successful.

```
Object {
  "geocoded_waypoints": Array [
    Object {
      "geocoder_status": "OK",
      "place_id": "ChIJ2YDFT9zweUgRgt5Tws6n3hs",
      "types": Array [
        "premise",
      ],
    },
    Object {
      "geocoder_status": "OK",
      "place_id": "ChIJW2PCihXxeUgRRWgA9kOzpjY",
      "types": Array [
        "establishment",
        "food",
        "lodging",
        "point_of_interest",
        "restaurant",
      ],
    },
  ],
  "routes": Array [
    Object {
      "bounds": Object {
        "northeast": Object {
          "lat": 52.9242042,
          "lng": -1.466251,
        },
        "southwest": Object {
          "lat": 52.9004767,
          "lng": -1.4801554,
        },
      },
      "copyrights": "Map data ©2018 Google",
      "legs": Array [
        Object {
          "arrival_time": Object {
            "text": "9:21am",
            "time_zone": "Europe/London",
            "value": 1524558107,
          },
          "departure_time": Object {
            "text": "8:56am",
            "time_zone": "Europe/London",
            "value": 1524556589,
          },
          "distance": Object {
            "text": "3.4 km",
            "value": 3407,
          },
          "duration": Object {
            "text": "25 mins",
            "value": 1518,
          },
          "end_address": "Full St, Derby DE1 3AF, UK",
          "end_location": Object {
            "lat": 52.9242042,
            "lng": -1.4756769,
          },
          "start_address": "50 Chatham St, Derby DE23 8TH, UK",
          "start_location": Object {
            "lat": 52.9004767,
            "lng": -1.480144,
          },
          "steps": Array [
            Object {
              "distance": Object {
                "text": "0.2 km",
                "value": 175,
              },
              "duration": Object {
                "text": "2 mins",
                "value": 123,
              },
              "end_location": Object {
                "lat": 52.900963,
                "lng": -1.478217,
              },
              "html_instructions": "Walk to Randolph Road",
              "polyline": Object {
                "points": "_c{aIza`Hm@BEyHC_Ag@S?H",
              },
              "start_location": Object {
                "lat": 52.9004767,
                "lng": -1.480144,
              },
              "steps": Array [
                Object {
                  "distance": Object {
                    "text": "26 m",
                    "value": 26,
                  },
                  "duration": Object {
                    "text": "1 min",
                    "value": 18,
                  },
                  "end_location": Object {
                    "lat": 52.9007148,
                    "lng": -1.4801554,
                  },
                  "html_instructions": "Head <b>north</b> on <b>Chatham St</b> toward <b>Randolph Rd</b>",
                  "polyline": Object {
                    "points": "_c{aIza`Hm@B",
                  },
                  "start_location": Object {
                    "lat": 52.9004767,
                    "lng": -1.480144,
                  },
                  "travel_mode": "WALKING",
                },
                Object {
                  "distance": Object {
                    "text": "0.1 km",
                    "value": 126,
                  },
                  "duration": Object {
                    "text": "1 min",
                    "value": 88,
                  },
                  "end_location": Object {
                    "lat": 52.9007561,
                    "lng": -1.4782714,
                  },
                  "html_instructions": "Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>Randolph Rd</b>",
                  "maneuver": "turn-right",
                  "polyline": Object {
                    "points": "md{aI~a`HEyHC_A",
                  },
                  "start_location": Object {
                    "lat": 52.9007148,
                    "lng": -1.4801554,
                  },
                  "travel_mode": "WALKING",
                },
                Object {
                  "distance": Object {
                    "text": "23 m",
                    "value": 23,
                  },
                  "duration": Object {
                    "text": "1 min",
                    "value": 17,
                  },
                  "end_location": Object {
                    "lat": 52.900963,
                    "lng": -1.478217,
                  },
                  "html_instructions": "Turn <b>left</b> onto <b>St Thomas Rd</b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Destination will be on the left</div>",
                  "maneuver": "turn-left",
                  "polyline": Object {
                    "points": "wd{aIdv_Hg@S?H",
                  },
                  "start_location": Object {
                    "lat": 52.9007561,
                    "lng": -1.4782714,
                  },
                  "travel_mode": "WALKING",
                },
              ],
              "travel_mode": "WALKING",
            },
            Object {
              "distance": Object {
                "text": "2.5 km",
                "value": 2460,
              },
              "duration": Object {
                "text": "15 mins",
                "value": 900,
              },
              "end_location": Object {
                "lat": 52.91829079999999,
                "lng": -1.4748049,
              },
              "html_instructions": "Bus towards Derby",
              "polyline": Object {
                "points": "_f{aIzu_HsPw@eHgW_IkOmHcPoLiNgKxQwHvL{LxKuK`G",
              },
              "start_location": Object {
                "lat": 52.900963,
                "lng": -1.478217,
              },
              "transit_details": Object {
                "arrival_stop": Object {
                  "location": Object {
                    "lat": 52.91829079999999,
                    "lng": -1.4748049,
                  },
                  "name": "Osmaston Road (Stop A8)",
                },
                "arrival_time": Object {
                  "text": "9:13am",
                  "time_zone": "Europe/London",
                  "value": 1524557580,
                },
                "departure_stop": Object {
                  "location": Object {
                    "lat": 52.900963,
                    "lng": -1.478217,
                  },
                  "name": "Randolph Road",
                },
                "departure_time": Object {
                  "text": "8:58am",
                  "time_zone": "Europe/London",
                  "value": 1524556715,
                },
                "headsign": "Derby",
                "line": Object {
                  "agencies": Array [
                    Object {
                      "name": "Arriva Midlands",
                      "url": "http://www.traveline.info/",
                    },
                  ],
                  "color": "#11416d",
                  "name": "Sapphire 38",
                  "text_color": "#ffffff",
                  "vehicle": Object {
                    "icon": "//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw2/6/bus2.png",
                    "name": "Bus",
                    "type": "BUS",
                  },
                },
                "num_stops": 9,
              },
              "travel_mode": "TRANSIT",
            },
            Object {
              "distance": Object { ... truncated from a larger response...
```

To debug my code my fetch function consists console.log() my attempt on trying to get to the data that i need, i particularly need to get to the departure information and i believe i am successful of doing so, here is my attempt:

```
fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=' + latitude + ',' + longitude + '&destination=' + goingto + '&mode=transit&transit_mode=bus&key=' + apiDirectionskey)
            .then((resdirections) => resdirections.json())
            .then((responseJson4) => {
                const departureloc = responseJson4.routes[0].legs[0].steps[1];
                console.log(departureloc);
```

the code above leads to the following JSON result:

```
Object {
  "distance": Object {
    "text": "3.1 km",
    "value": 3129,
  },
  "duration": Object {
    "text": "20 mins",
    "value": 1200,
  },
  "end_location": Object {
    "lat": 52.92222599999999,
    "lng": -1.471283,
  },
  "html_instructions": "Bus towards Derby",
  "polyline": Object {
    "points": "_f{aIzu_HsPw@eHgW_IkOmHcPoLiNgKxQwHvL{LxKuK`G{AqEJoPcU`A",
  },
  "start_location": Object {
    "lat": 52.900963,
    "lng": -1.478217,
  },
  "transit_details": Object {
    "arrival_stop": Object {
      "location": Object {
        "lat": 52.92222599999999,
        "lng": -1.471283,
      },
      "name": "Bus Station (Bay 19)",
    },
    "arrival_time": Object {
      "text": "9:45am",
      "time_zone": "Europe/London",
      "value": 1524645900,
    },
    "departure_stop": Object {
      "location": Object {
        "lat": 52.900963,
        "lng": -1.478217,
      },
      "name": "Randolph Road",
    },
    "departure_time": Object {
      "text": "9:24am",
      "time_zone": "Europe/London",
      "value": 1524644676,
    },
    "headsign": "Derby",
    "line": Object {
      "agencies": Array [
        Object {
          "name": "Arriva Midlands",
          "url": "http://www.traveline.info/",
        },
      ],
      "color": "#11416d",
      "name": "Sapphire 38",
      "text_color": "#ffffff",
      "vehicle": Object {
        "icon": "//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw2/6/bus2.png",
        "name": "Bus",
        "type": "BUS",
      },
    },
    "num_stops": 12,
  },
  "travel_mode": "TRANSIT",
}
```

as it shows it returns the actual JSON information that i need, and i want the transit information particularly the departure_stop location which looks like this:

```
"departure_stop": Object {
      "location": Object {
        "lat": 52.900963,
        "lng": -1.478217,
      },
      "name": "Randolph Road",
    }
```

I am in the process acquiring this data of the departure location so i can setState(). after initial tries of attempting to use .map() so i can aquire at latitude and longitude values, i am failing to get to do so as i am getting this:
 `[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'departureloc.map')]`

Here is my attempt:

```
 fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=' + latitude + ',' + longitude + '&destination=' + goingto + '&mode=transit&transit_mode=bus&key=' + apiDirectionskey)
            .then((resdirections) => resdirections.json())
            .then((responseJson4) => {
                //const departureloc = responseJson4.routes[0].legs[0].steps[1];
                const departureloc = responseJson4.routes[0].legs[0].steps[1];
                console.log(departureloc);
                let busscoords = departureloc.map((outcome) => {
                    return ( {
                                latitude: console.log(outcome.departure_stop.location.lat),
                                //longitude: outcome.departure_stop.location.lng,


                    });
                });
                //this.setState(console.log({ departureloc }));


            });
    }
```

Have i missed something? or what is my mistake? Any pointers on how to do this properly would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

actual JSON from:

```
 const departureloc = responseJson4.routes[0].legs[0].steps[1];
                    console.log(departureloc);

Object {
  "distance": Object {
    "text": "3.1 km",
    "value": 3129,
  },
  "duration": Object {
    "text": "21 mins",
    "value": 1260,
  },
  "end_location": Object {
    "lat": 52.92222599999999,
    "lng": -1.471283,
  },
  "html_instructions": "Bus towards Derby",
  "polyline": Object {
    "points": "_f{aIzu_HsPw@eHgW_IkOmHcPoLiNgKxQwHvL{LxKuK`G{AqEJoPcU`A",
  },
  "start_location": Object {
    "lat": 52.900963,
    "lng": -1.478217,
  },
  "transit_details": Object {
    "arrival_stop": Object {
      "location": Object {
        "lat": 52.92222599999999,
        "lng": -1.471283,
      },
      "name": "Bus Station (Bay 19)",
    },
    "arrival_time": Object {
      "text": "4:14pm",
      "time_zone": "Europe/London",
      "value": 1524669240,
    },
    "departure_stop": Object {
      "location": Object {
        "lat": 52.900963,
        "lng": -1.478217,
      },
      "name": "Randolph Road",
    },
    "departure_time": Object {
      "text": "3:52pm",
      "time_zone": "Europe/London",
      "value": 1524667961,
    },
    "headsign": "Derby",
    "line": Object {
      "agencies": Array [
        Object {
          "name": "Arriva Midlands",
          "url": "http://www.traveline.info/",
        },
      ],
      "color": "#11416d",
      "name": "Sapphire 38",
      "text_color": "#ffffff",
      "vehicle": Object {
        "icon": "//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw2/6/bus2.png",
        "name": "Bus",
        "type": "BUS",
      },
    },
    "num_stops": 12,
  },
  "travel_mode": "TRANSIT",
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `departureloc` is an `Object`, therefore you cannot use `.map` on it

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the **calling array**.

If you need to `map` on `Object`, use the [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) as it *returns an array of a given `object's` properties names* and use `setState` based on the `key'` properties.

and add a condition not to return undefined values as

```
Object.keys(departureloc).map(value => {
  if(departureloc[value] && departureloc[value].lat) {
     return //...
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, im doing you what you are suggesting but still getting the same error here is my attempt:                                        
`let busscoords = Object.keys(responseJson4.routes[0].legs[0].steps[1]).map((outcome) => {
                    return ( {
                                latitude: console.log(outcome.departure_stop.location.lat),
                                //longitude: outcome.departure_stop.location.lng,


                    });
                });
                //this.setState(console.log({ departureloc }));


            });
    }`

Comment: If the object is similar to the second `json` you've posted, then that should be correct

Comment: i have updated my post above with aditional actual json. here is my updated code  `let busscoords = Object.keys(responseJson4.routes[0].legs[0].steps[1].departure_stop.location).map((outcome) => {
                    return ({
                        latitude: console.log(outcome.lat),
                        //longitude: outcome.departure_stop.location.lng,
                    });` but im getting this error:                                 ` [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'responseJson4.routes[0].legs[0].steps[1].departure_stop.location')]`

Comment: Try this  `Object.keys(token).map(value => {
            console.log(token[value].lat)
        })` where `token` is your `departureloc` and check the logs, if it returns the lattitudes

Comment: yes this is the output: `16:46:10
undefined
16:46:10
undefined
16:46:10
52.92222599999999
16:46:10
undefined
16:46:10
undefined
16:46:10
52.900963
16:46:10
undefined
16:46:10
undefined`

Comment: Then if you dont want to return undefined values , you need to add a condition and check for them, whether they are undefined or not

Comment: thats great. i noticed that it printed both latitudes. what if i only want want one of them,departureloc[value].departure_stop.lat puts me back to undefined. `[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(departureloc).departure_stop.location')]`

Comment: `Object.keys(departureloc) && return you value`

Comment: is that within or after the map function if i return? like this?  `const stopmarkers = Object.keys(departureloc).map(value => (departureloc[value]) => ({
                    latlng: {
                        latitude: departure_stop.location`

Comment: Within the map function where you return, just add a condition to return only if not undefined

Comment: i have followed your suggestion and my result is this: 00:28:45
`Object {
  "lat": 52.915195,
  "lng": -1.466357,
}
00:28:45
undefined
00:28:45
undefined` ,  here is my latest code `const departureloc = responseJson4.routes[0].legs[0].steps[1].transit_details.departure_stop.location;
                console.log(departureloc);

    const stopmarkers = Object.keys(departureloc).map(value => { if (typeof ((departureloc[value]).lat) !== undefined) {
                        return { latitude: console.log((departureloc[value]).lat)}
                    } else { console.log('null'); }})`